# MySQL JOIN syntax precedence

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

```
members
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| mindex     | smallint(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| memberid   | smallint(5) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| forenames  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| surname    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| nameprefix | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| namesuffix | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| died       | smallint(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| notes      | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
memberships;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| mshipindex | smallint(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| memberid   | smallint(5) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| msid       | smallint(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| mstype     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| msyear     | smallint(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| msposition | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to search on memberships for a year (in `memberships.msyear`) and get `memberships.mstype` and `members.surname`.
I just can't get the right JOIN syntax on this.

Comment: You can use memeberid as key for joining

Answer (score 1):

You will use something like this:

```
select m.surname,
  s.mstype
from members m
left join memberships s
  on m.memberid = s.memberid
where s.msyear = yourYear
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea813/1)

I used a `LEFT JOIN` to return the all members, even those who might not have a membership record.  If the member does not have a record in the memberships table, then it will return null.

If you need help learning JOIN syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the syntax Here it is :

```
Select *
from members m
inner join membership ms on (m.memberid = ms.memberid)
where memberships.msyear = 2012
```